# symfony 1.4 add custom fields to frontend form

Tags: symfony-1.4

I need to add extra fields to my registration form in front end. I used [this](http://jmather.com/2010/10/09/customize-sfguarduser-sfdocrineguard/) article to add it to back end, and it works. Now I can't add them to front end.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add those fields to the form class used on your frontend.

For example let's say your frontend form class is called myClassForm, you would add your fields in lib/form/doctrine/MyClassForm.class.php

```
class MyClassForm extends BaseMyClassForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setWidget('extra_field1', new sfWidgetFormInput());
    $this->setWidget('extra_field2', new ....);

    //set validators
    $this->validatorSchema['extra_field1'] = ...;
  }
}
```